# pd.to_datetime add different date

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm working with dataframes like this one:

```
              lane      code      time  check       new
3      Lane 2 Op2  00:00:24       143    NaN     today
36     Lane 2 Op2      2347  00:04:26  144.0     today
40     Lane 2 Op2  00:00:43       144    NaN     today
66     Lane 2 Op2      2347  00:09:08  145.0     today
```

And my problem comes after  `d = pd.to_datetime(datafilter['time'], errors='coerce')` because pandas by default added today's date. I want to add different date (Which is a string) but after some documentation digging I found zero solutions to my problem.

```
3                       NaT
36      2021-12-09 00:04:26
40                      NaT
66      2021-12-09 00:09:08
68                      NaT
```

Comment: In your example it honestly looks like you have a data corruption in the reading of the data frame.  If you look at the code column some are putative times and some are codes.  Should not they be codes and missing so the times line up in the next column?

Comment: Rows with time in a code column are useless to me in my case and whole script runs just fine like this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did it;

```
datafilter['time'] = '2021-12-07 ' + datafilter['time'].astype(str)
d = pd.to_datetime(datafilter['time'], errors='coerce')
```

Adding date before pd.to_datetime gives exactly what I want:

```
 8     2021-12-08 00:00:38
16                     NaT
32     2021-12-08 00:02:49
```